# Publishing paid app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I published a paid app on Google Play but while buying the payment transaction was completed but it showed error saying

"Your order could not be processed Please Try again."

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you read the guidelines before asking a question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I suggest that in future instead of just telling the new user that this is the wrong place to ask a question that you should suggest another Stack Exchange site site.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you use the same account with which you are *selling* the app to *buy* the app as well.